# How to change title of a csv file in python(2.7)?

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I am a beginner and have the following data in a csv file and I want to change the 'account_key' to 'acct'. How should I go about doing it?

account_key,status,join_date,cancel_date,days_to_cancel,is_canceled
448,canceled,2014-11-10,2015-01-14,65,True
448,canceled,2014-11-05,2014-11-10,5,True
...
...
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is small enough to fit into main memory:

```
import csv

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    data = list(csv.reader(infile))
data[0][0] = 'acct'

with open('path/to/file', 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout)
    outfile.writerows(data)
```

If the file is too large to fit into main memory:

```
with open('path/to/file') as fin, open('path/to/output', 'w') as fout:
    infile = csv.reader(fin)
    header = next(infile)
    header[0] = 'acct'
    outfile.writerow(header)
    for row in infile:
        outfile.writerow(row)
```